# Implementing both requestSync and periodicSync in the same app

Tags: android, android-syncadapter, periodicity

I need to implement requestSync on button click and additionally periodic sync. I'm aware that requestSync isn't best practice, but that's just requirement, I have to do it.

Questions are:

1) if I set up periodic sync's pollFrequency to be 24hrs, and requestSync happened before 24hrs passed, will periodic sync will start counting from clean slate after requestSync or it will sync after 24hrs again?

2) What will happen if requestSync happened at the same time as periodic sync?

3) In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#addPeriodicSync(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20long)) it says pollFrequency has to be minimum 1hr, however I'm testing with 20 sec pollFrequency. Why is this possible?

4) syncing is happening not in 20 seconds but with varying intervals: 60secs, 5 secs, etc. Is this normal for intervals to be so different from each other?

5) Do I have to set some type of flag in the activity I'm setting periodic sync, that if it is first time the activity is being opened then set periodic sync, otherwise skip? Or system will know better than resetting same sync many times?